# How to get vertices of a triangle in constraint delaunay triangulation?

Tags: c++, triangulation, cgal, delaunay

I have written a program using cgal as follows:

```
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel       K;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_2<K>                      Vb;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_face_base_with_info_2<FaceInfo2,K>    Fbb;
typedef CGAL::Constrained_triangulation_face_base_2<K,Fbb>        Fb;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<Vb,Fb>               TDS;
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_tag                                Itag;
typedef CGAL::Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2<K, TDS, Itag>  CDT;
typedef CDT::Point                                                Point;
typedef CGAL::Polygon_2<K>                                        Polygon_2;

int main( )
{

  //construct two non-intersecting nested polygons  
  Polygon_2 polygon1;
  polygon1.push_back(Point(0,0));
  polygon1.push_back(Point(2,0));
  polygon1.push_back(Point(2,2));
  polygon1.push_back(Point(0,2));
  CDT cdt;
  insert_polygon(cdt,polygon1);
  CDT::Finite_faces_iterator t=cdt.faces_begin();

for (t = cdt.finite_faces_begin(); t != cdt.finite_faces_end(); t++)
    {
      //how can i achieve that?

    }

}
```

I want to get vertices of the triangles from `cdt.finite_faces_begin()` to triangle which `t` point to that in each iteration of the for loop.

for example In the first iteration of the loop, I get the vertices of the first triangle and in the second iteration of the loop, i get vertices of the first+second triangles and in the third one,i get vertices first+second+third triangles and so on.
how can i achieve that?

Comment: you should clarify what you want to obtain. When you loop over faces, in the loop body you can do something with the i'th face. If you want to do something for the first+second+..+i  you should maybe collect it in a container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in the i'th iteratotion you want just the three vertices of the face  use `for(inti=0;i<3;++i){t->vertex(i);}`, or `t->vertex(i)->point()`.

If you do not want to get a vertex that you already got from a previous face, you must use a `std::set<Vertex_handle>` that you declare outside the loop.